# echo characters only in one line with explode function php

Tags: php, function, explode

here is what i want to do

i am working with php explode function trying to limit characters it prints after defined condition

```
{ 
      $result=http://php.net
              new line characters i don't want to print
       $links =explode("://",$result);
          $nows=$links[1];
            echo $nows;
}
```

as you can see the above code will print

```
          php.net
          new line characters i don't want to print
```

but instead i want to stop printing after

```
php.net
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace newline characters with nothing:

```
$nows = str_replace("\n", "", $links[1]);
$nows = str_replace("\r", "", $nows);

echo $nows;
```

If you want only what is printed on the first line, try this:

```
$result = "php.net
           and some other text";

$nows = reset(explode("\n", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $result)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$nows = trim( $links[1] );
```

TRIM() will remove newlines among other things

[Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

EDIT:
Well now we have the actual situation which you say is :-

```
$result=http://php.net</br>nameserver:ns1</br>nameserver:ns2.
```

Try

```
$t = explode( '</br>', $result );
$t1 = explode ( '://', $t[0] );
echo $t1[1];
```

Just as a note, if it is you that is creating this string somewhere else `</br>` is not a valid html tag, it should be `<br>` or if you are using XHTML it should be `<br />`.

Comment: trim() does not completely remove newlines from a string, only from the beginning of a string and from the end of a string.

Comment: hello kaygeer can you help me with that the above solution of riggs dosn't work

Comment: @sukhjitdhot Well exactly where is the newline that you want to remove?

Comment: my result variable contain info like this $result=php.net</br>nameserver:ns1</br>nameserver:ns2..i want to print only php.net in result variable

Comment: @sukhjitdhot Does this answer get a tick then, or at least an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

If the part you're looking after will always be in the first line:

```
      $result="http://php.net
              new line characters i don't want to print";

       $links = explode("\n",$result);
/*
$links[0] ->http://php.net
$links[1] ->new line characters i don't want to print
*/
       $links =explode("://",$links[0]);
          $nows=$links[1];
            echo $nows;
/*
php.net
*/
```

Anyway , Consider giving more details about your case in order to offer a better way.
For instance , maybe regex?